# How do I format the output of route53-list-records to display specific information?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

I'd like to write a Python code which uses boto3 to query route53 and get Ip and "server role" which is part of each servers hostname.

I'm very new to Python and I'm having problems formatting the output I get.

My current code looks like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3

region = 'eu-west-1'
hostedzoneid = 'XXXXXXXX'
stackvpcid = 'vpc-xxxxxxx'

r53client = boto3.client('route53')

response = r53client.list_resource_record_sets(
        HostedZoneId=hostedzoneid,
        StartRecordName='dev',
        StartRecordType='A'
        )

#dict = {}
for resource in response['ResourceRecordSets']:
    print(resource)
```

The output looks like so:

```
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': 'ns-512.awsdns-00.net.'}, {u'Value': 'ns-1536.awsdns-00.co.uk.'}, {u'Value': 'ns-0.awsdns-00.com.'}, {u'Value': 'ns-1024.awsdns-00.org.'}], u'Type': 'NS', u'Name': 'vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 172800}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': 'ns-1536.awsdns-00.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400'}], u'Type': 'SOA', u'Name': 'vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 900}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.38.137'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-analytics1.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.17.224'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-analytics2.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.32.16'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-api1.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.26.94'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-api2.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.14.88'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-api4.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '52.154.154.22'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-bastion.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.41.124'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-batch1.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.39.163'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-cassandra1.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.14.5'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-cassandra2.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.31.112'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-cassandra3.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.38.137'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-kafka-10.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.41.124'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-kafka-20.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.32.16'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-kafka-30.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '172.58.26.94'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev-kafka-31.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': 'dev-mysql-14-vpc-XXXXXXXX.c1te7xcziik1.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com'}], u'Type': 'CNAME', u'Name': 'dev-mysql.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.', u'TTL': 300}
```

So now I'm trying to remove from the output all the lines that contain the word "kafka", the CNAME and the NS records, which I don't understand why they're displayed in the first place as I've configured a filter in the "list_resource_record_sets()".

Then, in each hostname, such as this for example:

```
Name': 'dev-cassandra3.vpc-XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.company.private.'
```

The server role would be the string "cassandra" or in other servers: analytics, api, bastion, etc... and the Ip would be the "Value".

So I would like the code to create a text list which will look like so:

```
172.58.31.112 : cassandra
52.154.154.22 : bastion
```

How is it done? I think my problem is that I don't know how to access the "Value" for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response['ResourceRecordSets']` is a list of ResourceRecords. Each ResourceRecords is a dictionary. The following should work or you can tweak it to your needs. You loop through the records and check if the name has the pattern `dev-([a-z]*)` and print the name and value.

```
import re

for resource in response['ResourceRecordSets']
  records = resource['ResourceRecords'][0]
  if 'Name' in resource:
    name = re.findall('dev-([a-z]*)', resource['Name'])
    if name:
      print records['Value'], name[0]
```

Output

```
172.58.38.137 analytics
172.58.17.224 analytics
172.58.32.16 api
172.58.26.94 api
172.58.14.88 api
52.154.154.22 bastion
172.58.41.124 batch
172.58.39.163 cassandra
172.58.14.5 cassandra
172.58.31.112 cassandra
172.58.38.137 kafka
172.58.41.124 kafka
172.58.32.16 kafka
172.58.26.94 kafka
dev-mysql-14-vpc-XXXXXXXX.c1te7xcziik1.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com mysql
```